# Where is right-click menu item / Intel HD Graphics Control Panel located on disk drive?

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, shortcut-file

I'd like to know where the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel is located on disk drive, or actually the executable that starts the control panel. I know how to access the intel graphic control panel with the mouse (which is: right click on desktop, and then select graphic properties), but that is not the question here. I have Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit, and my laptop is a HP Zbook.

The reason I want to know where the executable is, is that I want to make a shortcut to the control panel, and if possible also let the shortcut start in 'Beeldscherm' (which in English is something like 'screen'). See [here](http://prntscr.com/8dj4tc) a printscreen that hopefully clarifies.

I've searched in the Intel map on the c-drive and in the Intel-map on the start button, but I can't find it. Can you tell me where to look and where to look for? Or is there a way to figure out where an item in the right-click menu (after right clicking the desktop) is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I know is there's no way that you can access the Intel hd graphic, unless you install it manually like this article: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033915.htm

If you want to look the right-click menu option (we call it context menu), you can access it via regedit (run->regedit) and search this directory: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`.

Comment: thanks @vinc-richard. I'll dive into this deeper tomorrow. For now I can not figure out yet how to edit the ContextMenuHandlers, so I have to search for it first. Thanks so far!

Comment: I found it. I added a link to C:\Windows\System32\GfxUIEx.exe and it now woks as I wanted. I found the link in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INTEL\DISPLAY\igfxcui\igcfxcfg\resources. And there I found there was a link to C:\Windows\System32\GfxUIEx.exe. thanks @vinc-richard